# How to fetch linked permissions?

Tags: permissions

I'd like to see what actions my permissions are linked as a result of using `linkauth`.
The `v1/get_account` info does not return this information.

What other ways are there to look up what action a permission is linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dfuse.io has an endpoint for this: `/v0/state/permission_links`.
From the docs (docs.dfuse.io) under the REST API section:
GET /v0/state/permission_links: Fetching snapshots of any account’s linked authorizations on the blockchain, at any block height.

You can also use a block explorer that displays this graphically. eosq.app will display `linkauth`s in the permission tab of an account.